# Class constraint validator in form type class?

Tags: php, symfony-2.8

[In the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html#class-constraint-validator) it lists examples for applying a class validation constraint to Annotations, XML and YAML but not for PHP.

Since the validation is not applied to a property, where do I add this class validation constraint to the whole class inside a Symfony form type?

Comment: I'm looking exactly for the same, good question

Answer (score 5):

I think I've found a solution here: https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/custom-validation-property-path
There is a *tip* what says:

> If your form lives in a form type class, simply add the constraints key to the setDefaulOptions method.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the `setDefaultOptions` mentioned on the other answer, but managed to get it to work with `OptionsResolver::setDefaults`. It must have something to do with Symfony's version.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$resolver->setDefaults([
        'constraints' => [
            // list of constraints,
        ],
    ]);
```